# cannot group same value together laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, laravel

so I have a function which is:

```
public function checkTS(Request $request, $companyID)
{
  $data = DiraQuestion::where('status', 0)->get();

  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.checkTS', compact('data','companyID'));
}
```

from here I output a table like:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Entity Type</th>
      <th>Entity Value</th>
      <th>Synonym</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($data as $b)
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $b->id }}" readonly></td>
      <td>{{ucwords(strtok($b->eType, '_'))}}</td>
      <td>{{ucwords($b->eVal)}}</td>
      <td>{{ucwords($b->synonym)}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@viewTS', [$companyID, $b->id, $b->eType, $b->eVal])}}" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-black">View</a></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

currently, its showing me the output like:
[image: output]

and my database looks like:
[image: db]

as you can see from the first picture what I want to do is to group it together which has the same intent, eType, eVal from database so instead of showing all the values in the table it should only show 1 value which is already been group together by the same 3 value. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use group by for these in your Query.

```
public function checkTS(Request $request, $companyID)
 {
   $data = DiraQuestion::where('status', 0)
          ->groupBy('Your-cloumn')->get();

   return view('AltHr.Chatbot.checkTS', compact('data','companyID'));
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'althr.dev.dira_questions.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `dira_questions` where `status` = 0 group by `eVal`)

Comment: can you please define full code after you getting error

Comment: @AnilKumarSahu what do you mean?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: when this error occurs what code you write like for groupby();

Comment: the code i used is based on the answer provided by @Adnan Mumtaz here.

Comment: @AnilKumarSahu ^

Comment: name of group by column can you please define

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165463/discussion-between-j-doe-and-anil-kumar-sahu).

Comment: @AnilKumarSahu nope still same error, pls continue in chat

Answer (score 0):

You can group the same type of value by **groupBy('cloumn name')**

```
public function checkTS(Request $request, $companyID)
 {
   $data = DiraQuestion::where('status','=','0')
          ->groupBy('Your-cloumn')->get();

   return view('AltHr.Chatbot.checkTS', compact('data','companyID'));
 }
```

Comment: im having error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'althr.dev.dira_questions.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `dira_questions` where `status` = 0 group by `eVal`)

Answer (score 0):

TRy:

```
  $data = DiraQuestion::where('status', 0)
            ->groupBy('intent', 'eType', eVal')
            ->get();
```

Also to fix the error of '`isn't in GROUP BY`': 
in your `config/database.php`, inside the `mysql` settings, change the value of `'strict'` to false: 
 `'strict' => false,` 
 This will remove the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` when querying.